# How to formulate the integer program for this instance of the traveling salesman problem?

Tags: graph-theory, integer-programming, discrete-optimization

I'm having some trouble trying to formulate the integer program for the following instance of the travelling salesman problem.

Well, it is not quite a TSP, for it does not need for all nodes to be visited. In fact, an accepted solution is to visit only the starting node, although it may not be the objective solution.

The ideia is to find a route that maximizes the profit for a given graph with costs in the edges and profit in the vertices, while also returning to the origin vertex.

**The instance:** A complete graph $G = (V,E)$ with costs $c_e, e\in E$, between the vertices, profit $p_v, v \in V$, for each vertex and an origin vertex $v_o$.

**The solution:** A route $R=(v_o,v_1,v_2,\ldots,v_k,v_o)$ starting in $v_o$ with $k$ intermediate vertices $v_i \in V$, then returning to $v_o$. Each vertex in $V\setminus{v_o}$ can be contained only once in $R$.

**The objective:** To maximize the total value $v(R)=\sum_{i=1}^k{p_v}_i - (c_{v_o,v_1} + \sum_{i=1}^{k-1} c_{v_i,v_{i+1}} + c_{v_k,v_o})$

Any insight will be appreciated.

Comment: It looks like the formulation on page 10 of this paper is almost exactly what you are looking for: https://www.osti.gov/servlets/purl/6223080

Comment: @dbal Well, would you look at that. It's integer programming formulation certainly helped. I'll go on from there! Thanks a lot.

Comment: no problem! I would suspect you just have to put -B in their objective or something like that

Answer (score 3):

Ok, so, with the help of an article found and provide by @dbal, I could formulate the following:

\begin{alignat*}{2}
  & \text{maximize: } &\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n p_ix_{ij} - \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n c_{ij}x_{ij}& &\\
   & \text{subject to: }
          & \sum_{j=2}^n x_{1j} = 1 \tag1\\
        & & \sum_{j=1}^n x_{ij} \leq 1 & \quad \forall i \in V \tag2\\
        & & \sum_{i=1}^n x_{ij} - \sum_{k=1}^n x_{jk} = 0 & \quad \forall j \in V \tag3\\
        & & \sum_{i \in S} \sum_{j \in S} x_{ij} \leq |S|-1 & \quad \forall S \subset V \setminus \{1\} \tag4\\
        & & x_{ij} \in \{0,1\} & \quad \forall i \in V, \forall j \in V \tag5\\
        & & c_{ij},p_{i} \ge 0 & \quad \forall i \in V, \forall j \in V \tag6
\end{alignat*}

Validations would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Yes, this looks correct.  It is called the *prize-collecting TSP* or *optimal subtour problem*.

Comment: @RobPratt The notation is a bit wonky. You use both $\lbrace 1,\dots,n\rbrace$ and $V$ for the vertices. Also, (6) is presumably an assumption (unnecessary?) about the parameters, not a model constraint.

Comment: Also, there's the inevitable debate about TSP formulations -- use (4), which generates an exponential number of constraints, or the MTZ formulation (more compact but weaker). Having taken a class from Tucker, I'm biased in favor of the latter. :-)

Comment: Thanks for all comments. @prubin Yes, while writing code for the solver, I realized that and have modified it using MTZ. I am not used to the notation, but now I see your point! I shall review it.